# Java - Data sorting code, output is not what it should be

Tags: java

Hey guys so I have to do an assignment were we sort through some weather data and I got most of it done but I am not getting results I should. (EDIT) Here is a link to the file: http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/~bsetzer/2302sp15/extra/data/636870-99999-2013.op.
The results that I am getting look like:

```
Station ID: 636870      
WBAN ID: 99999      
Year: 2013      
Max average temp: 68.0      
Min average temp: 63.1       
Max max temp: 89.6      
Min min temp: 51.8      
Average visibility: 73.18993288590602      
149 lines counted.
```

But the output should look like this.

```
Station id:          636870      
WBAN id:             99999      
Year:                2013      
Max Average Temp:    78.6      
Min Average Temp:    60.8       
Max Max Temp:        91.4      
Min Min Temp:        51.8      
Average visibility:  6.535507246376822      
Number of fog days:  4
```

My code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){

    File infile = new File("636870-99999-2013.op");
    int totalLineCount = 0;
    int stnNumber = 0;
    int wbanNumber = 0;
    int year = 0;
    double meanTemp = 0;
    double mtemp = 0;
    double minmt = 1000;
    double maxmt = 0;
    double maxTemp = 0;
    double mtemp2 = 0;
    double minTemp = 1000;
    double mtemp3 = 0;
    double aV = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0.0;

    try {
        Scanner inscan = new Scanner(infile);



        while (inscan.hasNext()) {

            String line = inscan.nextLine();
            String line2 = inscan.nextLine();
            //STN Number
            String stnNumberField = line2.substring(0, 6);
            String stnNumberTrimmed= stnNumberField.trim();
            stnNumber = Integer.parseInt(stnNumberTrimmed);

            //wban number
            String wbanNumberField = line2.substring(7, 12);
            String wbanNumberTrimmed = wbanNumberField.trim();
            wbanNumber = Integer.parseInt(wbanNumberTrimmed);

            //year
            String yearField = line2.substring(14, 18);
            String yearFieldTrimmed = yearField.trim();
            year = Integer.parseInt(yearFieldTrimmed);

            //average temp
            String meanTempField = line2.substring(24, 30);
            String meanTempFieldTrimmed = meanTempField.trim();
            mtemp = Double.parseDouble(meanTempFieldTrimmed);
            //min average temperature
            if (mtemp != 99.99 && mtemp != 999.9 && mtemp != 9999.9){
                if( mtemp < minTemp){
                    minmt = mtemp;
                }
            }
            if (mtemp != 9999.9){
                if (mtemp > maxTemp){
                    maxmt = maxTemp;
                }
            }


            //max temp
            String maxTempField = line2.substring(102, 108);
            String maxTempFieldTrimmed = maxTempField.trim();
            mtemp2 = Double.parseDouble(maxTempFieldTrimmed);
            if (mtemp2 != 9999.9){
                if (mtemp2 > maxTemp){
                    maxTemp = mtemp2;
                }
            }

            //min temp
            String minTempField = line2.substring(110, 116);
            String minTempFieldTrimmed = minTempField.trim();
            mtemp3 = Double.parseDouble(minTempFieldTrimmed);
            if (mtemp3 != 99.99 && mtemp3 != 999.9 && mtemp3 != 9999.9){
                if( mtemp3 < minTemp){
                    minTemp = mtemp3;
                }
            }

            //average visibility
            String averageVisibility = line2.substring(68, 73);
            String averageVisibilityTrimmed = averageVisibility.trim();
            aV = Double.parseDouble(averageVisibilityTrimmed);
            // read data and compute statistics
                double value = aV;
                sum += value;
                count++;


            //fog indicator
            char fogIndicator = line2.getChars(132);



            totalLineCount++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    double average = sum / count;

    System.out.println("Station ID: " + stnNumber);
    System.out.println("WBAN ID: " + wbanNumber);
    System.out.println("Year: " + year);
    System.out.println("Max average temp: " + maxmt);//why is this incorrect?
    System.out.println("Min average temp: " + minmt);//why is this incorrect?
    System.out.println("Max max temp: " + maxTemp); //why is this output incorrect?
    System.out.println("Min min temp: " + minTemp);
    System.out.println("Average visibility: " + average);
    //Number of fog days:  11

    System.out.println(totalLineCount + " lines counted." );


} }
```

Comment: without knowing what the file looks like there's not a ton we can help with.

Comment: I don't know why `char fogIndicator = line2.getChars(132);` compiles, or should I say, it doesn't compile for me.

Comment: it doesn't compile but my professor says it should and here is a link to the data file http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/~bsetzer/2302sp15/extra/data/636870-99999-2013.op

Comment: I dislike that someone put this on hold, because that prevents me from submitting an answer. I would suggest instead of using substring, to split each line using "[ ]+" the space in between the brackets is the character to split by, and the + means to treat consecutive of that character as one. If you split the line by that, what you will have is a String array with the data, index 0 would be STN, index 1 would be WBAN, index 2 would be YEARMODA, etc. This would be far easier to parse and not requiring trimming.

Comment: "...must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself..."

Doesn't "The output should be ..." count as that... The desired behavior is stated there, at nearly the beginning of the question.

Comment: Yeah D3_JMultiply I thought I included all the information necessary. I couldn't think of anything else to add. And thank you for your tip but I used parse because that is how my professor wants us to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ignored `char fogIndicator = line2.getChars(132);` because it wouldn't compile and has no visible effect.

Now to your Problem. In your **while-loop** you scan the next line twice so you wouldn't scann the header line. If you move the first `nextLine()`before your while-loop everything should work just fine!

Your previous code wouldn't parse the header line, but also would jump over every second line.

Example:

```
String line = inscan.nextLine();
while (inscan.hasNext()) {
    String line2 = inscan.nextLine();
    //...
```

**Edit:**
This doesn't fixed the average Temp.

```
if (mtemp < minTemp) {
    minmt = mtemp;
//...
if (mtemp > maxTemp) {
    maxmt = maxTemp;
```

Instead of comparing it to your minTemp you should compare it to your avgMinTemp (minmt). Similar Problem with avgMaxTemp.

```
if (mtemp < minmt ) {
    minmt = mtemp;
//...
if (mtemp > maxmt) {
    maxmt = mtemp;
```

To fix your avgVisibility you just have to add your filter statement, which you forgot at this line.

```
if (value != 99.99 && value != 999.9 && value != 9999.9) {
    sum += value;
    count++;
}
```

And at last your fogindicator. Instead of getChars(); use charAt(int pos); which compiles and returns the wanted character.

```
char fogIndicator = line2.charAt(132);
if(fogIndicator == '1')
    fog++;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Well that fixed Max max temp and the min min temp. So thank you for that , now I just need to figure out why the rest are not working.

Comment: I was to fast, wasn't I.
The average values and fog days still aren't correct.

Comment: no dude thanks for the quick response. and that did solve a bit of the problem

Comment: no prob :) I edited my post. Now it should cover all problems ;)

Comment: thank you so much. that char thing almost worked but now instead of a  number it outputs a square. and now the only number that is wrong is the max average temp because it is reading a temperature out of a completely different line.

Comment: OK got everything but the max average temp worked out